# Pull all images with specific tag from repository

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I want to pull all the images with tag `1.2.0` from [here](https://hub.docker.com/u/openshift/).

Is this possible?

Comment: "...how do I have to pull ..." This is confusing and I don't see a question. If you meant "Why do I have to pull ...", that's one thing but I'm not sure that's your main question.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You pull specific tags with the following syntax:

```
docker pull fedora:1.0
```

---

From your new question, you appear to want to pull multiple repositories from a specific login on Docker Hub. I'm not aware of a command that supports this but you should be able to script the `docker search` output.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know, you need to fetch the name of the images, and then batch pull them using "docker pull openshift/xxx:1.2.0"

Comment: as @BMitch metioned you can script docker search output, but only a few images got:  docker search openshift | grep  ^openshift*  | awk -F  ' ' '{print "docker pull "$1":1.2.0"}'